# Integrate: $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \xi^{a - 1}(1-\xi)^{b-1}\mathrm d\xi \, dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $a,b>0$ be positive real numbers. Integrate the following expression:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \xi^{a - 1}(1-\xi)^{b-1}\mathrm d\xi \, dx$$

Comment: why the close vote? Leave a comment please.

Comment: Usually down votes appear when no effort from the author of the question is given in any form. In this case a question is being asked but no ideas as  to what has been tried, what the ideas are, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to evaluate this integral set.

**Method 1**

Given 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \xi^{a - 1}(1-\xi)^{b-1}\mathrm d\xi \, dx$$
then a change of integration may be applied for which the integral becomes
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} \xi^{a - 1}(1-\xi)^{b-1} \, \left( \int_{\xi}^{1} \frac{dx}{x} \right) \, d\xi &= \int_{0}^{1} (- \ln(\xi)) \, \xi^{a - 1}(1-\xi)^{b-1} \, d\xi \\
&= - \partial_{a} \int_{0}^{1} \xi^{a - 1}(1-\xi)^{b-1} \, d\xi \\
&= - \partial_{a} B(a,b) = - \frac{d}{da} \, \frac{\Gamma(a) \Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)} \\
&= B(a,b) \, (\psi(a+b) - \psi(a)).
\end{align}

**Method 2**

Using the incomplete Beta function in series form, namely,
$$\int_{0}^{x} t^{a-1} \, (1-t)^{b-1} \, dt = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1-b)_{n}}{n! \, (a + n)} \, x^{n+a}$$
then
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \xi^{a - 1}(1-\xi)^{b-1}\mathrm d\xi \, dx &= 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1-b)_{n}}{n! \, (a + n)} \, \int_{0}^{1} x^{n+a-1} \, dx \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1-b)_{n}}{n! \, (a + n)^{2}} \\
&= - \partial_{a} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1-b)_{n}}{n! \, (a + n)} = - \partial_{a} B(a,b) \\
&= B(a,b) \, (\psi(a+b) - \psi(a)). 
\end{align}

Comment: The first method is very nice. Thanks.